# Am getting empty arrays from crawled data from certain website what could be problem?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am getting empty arrays from crawled data from certain website what could be problem?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from jumia.items import JumiaItem


class LaptopsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name="laptops"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.jumia.co.ke/laptops/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for laptops in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, '-gallery')]"):
            loader = ItemLoader(item=JumiaItem(), selector=laptops, response=response)
            loader.add_xpath('brand', ".//span[contains(@class, 'brand')]/text()")
            loader.add_xpath('name', ".//span[@class='name']/text()")
            loader.add_xpath('price', ".//span[@class='price-box ri']/span[contains(@class, 'price')][1]/span[@dir='ltr']/text()")
            loader.add_xpath('link', ".//a[@class='link']/@href")
            yield loader.load_item()
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@title='Next']/@href").extract_first()

        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)

            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Have you pulled the page directly from a browser or some other direct HTTP(S) GET request and verified that what you are looking for exists in the response? Can you provide a sample of the page content you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked in `scrapy shell` and it seems there are some blocks without needed info. Check these results:

```
In [2]: len(response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, '-gallery')]").extract())
Out[2]: 48

In [3]: len(response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, '-gallery')]//span[contains(@class, 'brand')]").extract())
Out[3]: 40
```

So there are 48 blocks, but only 40 of them are valid.
So I offer to make small check on needed data in your `for` loop (for example check name or brand) and if it is absent, just `continue`.

Comment: Great! That has helped a lot. It has worked. Thanks